# Z3 Java API toString() Doesn't Print Unused Declarations

Tags: java, z3, smt

I have a context with only the following datatype declaration:

```
EnumSort signal = ctx.mkEnumSort("signal", "red", "yellow", "green");
```

What I want is to get an equivalent SMTLIB representation of the above declaration, something like the following:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((signal red yellow green)))
```

How do I convert this? I tried creating a solver for this context and then doing `solver.toString()` but it doesn't print anything unless I use this declaration in an assertion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only convert to smtlib from a `Solver` (or `Optimize`) object. Think of context as a "manager" of sorts, that is independent of smt-lib or any particular representation. And you are correct that you'll have to assert something about this object, which is rather annoying.

Having said that, internally your `signal` value will be stored as a `Sort` object: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classz3_1_1sort.html. (In your case, whatever the Java equivalent of this class is.) In theory, one can then scrutinize this object to figure out it's a datatype, get the constructors etc., to do the translation by hand; but that'll be quite representation dependent and likely to be error-prone in the long run.